# Create custom predicate function in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to define a custom predicate in T-SQL? So that for instance I can write:

```
SELECT a,b,c 
FROM MyTable
WHERE dbo.myCustomPredicate(a)
```

An easy workaround is to create a scalar-valued function dbo.myCustomPredicate which returns a BIT, and change the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE dbo.myCustomPredicate(a)=1
```

Just curious if it's possible to avoid the "=1".

Comment: No; there is no Boolean data type in SQL.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens -  SQL:1999 has a boolean datatype.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Correction: T-SQL has no Boolean datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this isn't possible.

SQL Server doesn't support the ANSI SQL boolean datatype.

You don't say what the implementation of `dbo.myCustomPredicate` is but quite likely `WHERE dbo.myCustomPredicate(a)=1` should be avoided as well on the grounds of both Sargability and general performance of Scalar UDFs in SQL Server.

Comment: Indeed.  UDFs in a where clause will tend to force a table scan...a Very Bad Thing in terms of performance.